# Can anybody explain me the role of @required and @optional concept when I create my own @protocol?

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I have to create my own `@protocol` and `@delegation` in my interface. I read about this functionality and I understood it but I don't know the role of `@required` and `@optional` in `@protocol`.

Why I have to use it? The `@protocol` will works the same if I don't separate my methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@required` methods have to be implemented when a class implements a protocol, and `@optional` methods do not necessary have to be implemented.

By default, all methods declared in a protocol are required methods.

Comment: @user3042608 No problem, you can mark your question as answered :)

Comment: I'm new here, I don't know how :">

Comment: I did it at least. :) @MartinMoizard